# Dynamic table name for Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For my application I will have multiple tables with the same base structure (auto generated tables). For example I have the table `survey_1`, `survey_2` and`survey_23`. Is it possible to create a model like this: `new Survey(2)` that will generate a Model for table `survey_2`?

Comment: You do it wrong. Put all data into one table, and add column to separate data into logical pieces.

Comment: No, I need mutliple tables because I am making survey table where every column is for a specific question type and every row will be for the answers of the person who fills in the survey. My task is to build it this way so I can't change the database structure.

Comment: @BartBergmans There are ways of handling that that don't require a new table for each survey.

Comment: Like I said, I have to build it like this. I can't do anything about that.

Comment: Part of your job as a software professional is making a case to non-technical management when a requirement doesn't make sense. Sometimes we get impossible/dangerous requirements, or just stupid ones. "Nothing I can do about it" is rarely literally true.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757452/laravel-eloquent-accessing-properties-and-dynamic-table-names

Answer (score 3):

I've got this. In laravel 6.
I haven't settled on the idea yet, I'm thinking I rather have multiple databases and use separate connections... But that's not in the question.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = null;
   
    protected $fillable = [
        'data',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'object',
    ];

    public function setTable($tableName)
    {
        $this->table = $tableName;
    }

    public function scopeTable($query, $tableName)
    {
        $query->getQuery()->from = $tableName;
        return $query;
    }

}
```

test paths:

```
Route::get('/write', function () {

    $project = new \App\Models\Eloquent\Project();
    $project->setTable('project_2');
    $project->data = ['hello' => 'dolly'];
    $project->save();

});

Route::get('/read', function () {

    $data = \App\Models\Eloquent\Project::query()
        ->table('project_2')
        ->where('data', 'like', '%dolly%')
        ->get();

    return $data;

});
```

But this works.
O. Yes. I put my models in App\Models\Eloquent ... That's optional.

Comment: how to update bro?

Comment: @Sahidrahutomo everything the docs say is same. "->table('project_2')" just sets the "protected $table = null;" with a real table name.  ->delete() ->update() ->whatever() is all the same.  You can create your own ->methods(), that's what chaining is for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. Try to override `__constructor` method in your model

```
class Survey extends Model
{
    public function __construct( array $attributes = [] )
    {
        parent::construct($attributes);
        if (array_key_exists('table', $attributes)) {
           $this->setTable($attributes['table']) ;
        }
        else {
            // do staff when table is not specified 
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
$survey_1 = new Survey(['table' => 'survey_1']); 
$survey_2 = new Survey(['table' => 'survey_2']); 
$survey_3 = new Survey(['table' => 'survey_3']);
```

I don't know will it work or not.
But I STRONGLY recommend you don't use your approach with separate tables.

Comment: There is one MASSIVE drawback to doing this (which I just encountered while talking to a colleague today). Some Eloquent methods like `firstOrCreate` create a *new* instance which will completely ignore your $table name. There is currently no way around this.